# Aligning Twitter Bootstrap inline form group to the right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following markup.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>Title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="TrackId">Track:</label>
            <select class="form-control mb-2 mx-sm-4" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Track: field is required." id="TrackId" name="TrackId">
                <option selected="selected" value="1">Track A</option>
                <option value="2">Track B</option>
                <option value="3">Track C aslkdfjaksdfjlskjdflaksdjfklasjdlksdjf</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it looks something like this:

[image]

How can I right-align my `<label>` and `<select>` elements within the container `<div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `ml-auto` to your `form-group` div should do the trick

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>Title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 form-inline">
    <div class="form-group ml-auto">
      <label for="TrackId">Track:</label>
      <select class="form-control mb-2 mx-sm-4" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Track: field is required." id="TrackId" name="TrackId">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">Track A</option>
        <option value="2">Track B</option>
        <option value="3">Track C aslkdfjaksdfjlskjdflaksdjfklasjdlksdjf</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still have a right margin I need to address, but this seems to right align it. Can you explain why? The documentation I found for `ml-auto` isn't very complete.

Comment: `ml-auto` will add the largest margin it can for the left side of the div. What this then achieves is pushing your `form-group` div as far to the right as it can possibly sit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap's utility classes `d-flex` and `align-items-center` in this case. See the snippet below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <h4>Title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group d-flex align-items-center gap-3">
      <label for="TrackId">Track:</label>
      <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Track: field is required." id="TrackId" name="TrackId">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">Track A</option>
        <option value="2">Track B</option>
        <option value="3">Track C aslkdfjaksdfjlskjdflaksdjfklasjdlksdjf</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you convert these utility classes into CSS then it just means:

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: row; /*default value for `flexbox`*/
align-items: center;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. And when I run your snippet, it just takes up the entire width.

Comment: @JonathanWood it's because it's being viewed on smaller screen when you haven't considered smaller screen in your code. Just like how you have `col-md-6` you can also set `col-sm-6` to make it responsive. I've edited the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `.justify-content-between` class together with the `.row` class.

```
<div class="row justify-content-between">
....
</div>
```

and the flex does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Code should be like this,

```
<div class="row justify-content-between">
    // Other elements here
</div>
```

**.justify-content-between** this is build in class from BS5. Hope simply this will be worked, lets try it.